# How to clear cache/clear data google play store in programmatically?

Tags: android, google-play, app-store

Since, play store got problem to update apps instantly instead, have to clear cache/ clear data before can get update apps. I try use this code:

```
 try {
                                    // clearing app data
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm clear com.android.vending");

     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

or try to go google playstore>app info>storage by using below code:

```
try { //
                                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.finsky.activities.SettingsActivity");
                                    intent.setClassName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.SettingsActivity");
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                catch(Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

neither of this working for me. Please help me clear to this problem.tq

Comment: Any solution for this?